# On hover show current time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that hide/shows the time on hover with a timeout.
But now i want to make it show the time of the one users hovers.
I know that it must be done with the $(this) but i cant get it work.

The JsFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/z332ozjs/

```
<p class="div">
    <span class="time">[20:33:49]</span>
    Time 1
</p>
<p class="div">
    <span class="time">[21:35:49]</span>
    Time 2
</p>


var msgTime = $('.div');
var time = $('span.time');
time.hide();
var x;
msgTime.hover(
    function () {
        x = setTimeout( function() {  
            $(this).find(time).show();
        }, 100);
     }, 
     function () {
        clearInterval(x);
         $(this).find(time).hide();
     }
);
```

Comment: fyi - don't mix the `set...` and `clear...` functions.

Comment: also, `.find` takes another selector, not another jquery object.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure CSS solution:

```css
.time {
  display: none;
}
.div:hover .time {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p class="div">
    <span class="time">[20:33:49]</span>
    Time 1
</p>
<p class="div">
    <span class="time">[21:35:49]</span>
    Time 2
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a pure CSS solution would probably be the best in this case, [as shown by Chris Pietschmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28773316/3928341).

If you want to do it with minor changes to the approach you already took, here is one way to go about it ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z332ozjs/4/)):

Instead of calling `hide()` on the `span` holding the time, we just make it hidden by default and show/hide it depending on the hover status.

Further, using class `.div` for your time holding divs is probably a bad idea since it will select all divs on your page. Using something more specific like `div-time` would be better.

As far as not knowing how to use `$(this)`, jquery event selectors automatically transfer the context (i.e. `this`) within an event callback to correspond to the element on which the event happened.

Another thing, you are passing a jquery object to the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) jquery function but what this function takes as an argument is a selector string and uses it to find elements within the jquery element on which find was called. So, you need to change:

```
$(this).find(time)     // dont pass-in the jquery object "time"
```

To:

```
$(this).find('.time') // pass in the selector matching the class "time"
```

So, when the user hovers over an element, what you can do is:

```
 $(this)         // select hovered element
  .find('.time') // find the time span within it
  .show();       // show the time
```

Here's how the code would look:

```js
var msgTime = $('.div-time');
msgTime.hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.time').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('.time').hide();
  }
);
```

```css
.time {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="div-time">
  <span class="time">[20:33:49]</span>
  Time 1
</p>
<p class="div-time">
  <span class="time">[21:35:49]</span>
  Time 2
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems.

First,  inside `setTimeout` you lose the context of `this` due to closure .

To search for an instance using `find()` use the actual selector

```
    var msgTime = $('.div');
    var time = $('span.time');
    time.hide();
    var x;
    msgTime.hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this); //store reference of element
            x = setTimeout( function() {  
                $this.find('.time').show();// look for actual class
            }, 100);
         }, 
         function () {
            clearInterval(x);
             $(this).find('.time').hide();
         }
    );
```

Seems very confusing to use a class of `div` on a `<p>` tag. On a large application this could cause much confusion

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z332ozjs/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

your css:

```
.div:hover .time{
    display:inline-block
}
.time{
    display:none;
}
```

your html:

```
<p class="div">
    <span class="time" >[20:33:49]</span>
    Time 1
</p>
<p class="div">
    <span class="time" >[21:35:49]</span>
    Time 2
</p>
```